# Microsoft's remotewipe script causing a session/CimException

Tags: powershell

When I run the script below on one machine, it ran perfectly.  (The outcome is a reboot that then reinstalls a fresh install of Windows with no user data or applications or system info saved.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dmwmibridgeprov/mdm-remotewipe?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
$namespaceName = "root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className = "MDM_RemoteWipe"
$methodName = "doWipeMethod"

$session = New-CimSession

$params = New-Object Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimMethodParametersCollection
$param = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimMethodParameter]::Create("param", "", "String", "In")
$params.Add($param)

try
{
    WARNING!!$instance = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className -Filter "ParentID='./Vendor/MSFT' and InstanceID='RemoteWipe'"
    DELETE!!$session.InvokeMethod($namespaceName, $instance, $methodName, $params)
}
catch [Exception]
{
    write-host $_ | out-string
}
```

WARNING: You will have to delete the "WARNING!!" and "DELETE!!" text in the code above if you want it to run.  When you execute this Powershell script successfully, it wipes an entire PC.  I did not want anyone to do this accidentally, so this was added to intentionally break it.  (These words are not in my script, and are not the cause of my problems.)

When I ran it on the second machine, I received various errors;

If running as an administrator in Powershell, but NOT running as system:

```
The requested object could not be found.
```

If running as system with administrator privileges:

```
A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
```

To troubleshoot, under:

```
    write-host $_ | out-string
```

I added:

```
    write-host session $session namespacename $namespaceName instance $instance methodname $methodName params $params param $param | out-string
    $_ | out-file .\error.txt
```

Which then gives me the output (first on screen, then contents of error.txt):

```
A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.

session CimSession: . namespacename root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap instance MDM_RemoteWipe (InstanceID = "RemoteWipe", ParentID = "./Vendor/MSFT") methodname doWipeMethod params param = "" param param = ""
```

```
A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At C:\TEMP\DO-NOT-USE_wipe_computer.ps1:14 char:5
+     $session.InvokeMethod($namespaceName, $instance, $methodName, $pa ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CimException
```

So I think maybe we're not successfully opening a CimSession.  I check if I can open a CimSession:

```
$session = New-CimSession
$session
```

And I can, with the result:

```
Id           : 5
Name         : CimSession5
InstanceId   : 4f07e61d-1686-472a-a84e-d96347f700e6
ComputerName : localhost
Protocol     : DCOM
```

So I guess it's now stuck on the params/param not pulling the required info.  But I'm stuck on that and not sure how to test or resolve.

Update: I have verified that the target machine does have the appropriate CIMClass available.

```
get-cimclass -namespace root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap | where {$_.CimClassName -eq "MDM_RemoteWipe"}
```

```
CimClassName                        CimClassMethods     
CimClassProperties
------------                        ---------------      ------------------
MDM_RemoteWipe                      {doWipeMethod, do... {InstanceID, ParentID}
```

If we remove the [exception] from catch, the error changes to:
Exception calling "InvokeMethod" with "4" argument(s): "A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code."

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if Windows RE is not enabled. Check by running (as an administrator)

```
Reagentc /info
```

Windows RE must be enabled in order for the RemoteWipe CSP to function.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/device-management/remotewipe-fails-sending-dowipe-command